# CCAvenue Integration

Tags: php, android, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I'm new in payment gateway integration. I have to integrate CCAvenue payment gateway integration in my project(CORE PHP). But I don't know that how to create merchant account for developer testing, how to get merchant key etc. I have done R&D, but all link describes from middle. In my project, I got order details from android application using JSON. If anyone know answer then please explain or suggest me link from where I can understand from beginning. Thank You.

Comment: as far as i know ccavenue not supporting testing. and if you want testing merchant id and access code than download this https://mars.ccavenue.com/downloads/Mobile_Integraion_Kit.zip in this zip file they have included prepared code and all that thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while working on cc-avenue u should know that their is no sandbox or testing account . if you want test url of ccavenue you can get it after you register a merchant account in ccavenue .
and for integration of ccavenue account they provide you integration kit for all lanuaguage php,node.js,java ,asp etc. Please note that you can not test anything unless you have a valid account in ccavenue which will be given by them and that account take 3 day for verification and registered . For any query you can ask.